# Single column diagrams in double column pages

Tags: microsoft-word, images

I was writing a conference paper, and I wanted to know how to insert single column large images in middle of double column text.

Copy pasting the image in the middle really messes up the data and also the formatting.

Comment: Have you tried using a section break at the point where you want to insert the image so you can set to single column, then another section break to put it back to double-column after?

Comment: I will try that now